# How do I print the data from a dictionary within a list based on a users input?

Tags: python

I have a list and i need to print the information for whoever the user searches for by name. how can i do it?

```
name_list = [
    {'id': 1 , 'name': 'Bobby A', 'position': 'Executive' , 'pay': '$168280' , 'Date hired': '1/1/2008' , 'Job position': 'Senior IT director'},
    {'id': 2 ,'name': 'Tommy G', 'position': 'Supervisor' , 'pay': '$122,338' , 'Date hired': '6/29/2008' , 'Job position': 'IT director'},
    {'id': 3 ,'name': 'Ronny R', 'position': 'Supervisor' , 'pay': '$120,990' , 'Date hired': '12/16/2008' , 'Job position': 'Software engineer'},
    {'id': 4 ,'name': 'Bill C', 'position': 'Associate' , 'pay': '$95,648' , 'Date hired': '1/18/2010' , 'Job position': 'IT consultant'},
    {'id': 5 ,'name': 'Sally Z', 'position': 'Associate' , 'pay': '$86,560' , 'Date hired': '4/21/2010' , 'Job position': 'Web developer'} 
]
```

Comment: If you have control over this structure, it would be better if the whole thing was a dict according to the names: `name_list = {'Bobby': {...}, 'Tommy': {...}, ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over the list, then search for the key that you want, in this case `name` is the key. finally you'll print the whole dictionary. let's say we are looking for `'Ronny R'`, we can do it like this :

```
name_to_look_for = 'Ronny R'
for i in range(len(name_list)):
    if name_list[i]['name']== name_to_look_for:
        print(name_list[i])
```

or you can do it using foreach loop :

```
name_to_look_for = 'Ronny R'
for name in name_list:
    if name['name']== name_to_look_for:
        print(name)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reformat and the answer :)